# How will I know what is the app server installed in my rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, appserver

I installed rails in windows, is there a command to know what is the version of app server installed in in my rails? What is command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of rails is specified in the gemfile

When you say rails new my_app , it generates an entire project(app, log, config, db etc).  A gemfile would also be generate . If you open the gemfile you will be able to find the version of your rails.

You will find something like gem rails , '3.2.1'

Comment: Thank you,
I already did this and I have Rails 3.2.8, but I want to know what is the installed server to serve rails, e.g. want to know if its unicorn, ngix or apache etc.. what is the command for verifying what app server installed in my rails?

Comment: Same deal. You specify the webserver in the gemfile and it gets loaded when you run rails.

Comment: How will I specify the webserver in the gemfile?

Comment: The default server for rails is WEBrick.  But if you want to use it with other servers(say apache) you have to install apache and configure the .conf file to host you app.   Check http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2007/01/configuration-of-web-servers-and-rails.html for more information .  Also, Check out http://rubyonrails.org/deploy . Passenger runs apache and is really easy to set up .

Answer (score 0):

When you run the server you can see the server name and version.
Eg.
run rails s

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http:

=> Call with -d to detach

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2012-09-24 12:23:38] INFO  **WEBrick 1.3.1**

[2012-09-24 12:23:38] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

[2012-09-24 12:23:38] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=10116 port=3000